# Convert large matrix to binary rating matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix which has information about which item the user has viewed i.e 1= item viewed and 0= item not viewed. This matrix is a very large matrix with dimensions 9276 x 13068. But whenever I try converting it into binaryRatingMatrix using

```
binmatrix<- as(user_asset_matrix2,"binaryRatingMatrix")
binmatrix
2 x 2 rating matrix of class ‘binaryRatingMatrix’ with 3 ratings.
```

it forms a 2x2 matrix which is of no use. After converting binmatrix back to matrix it is converted to:

```
  0        1 
0 TRUE     TRUE
1 TRUE     FALSE
```

Can anyone give me a solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Which are the dimensions of `user_asset_matrix2`?

Comment: are you using recommenderlab? when I convert the bin matrix back to a normal matrix, I get the same dimensions as the original matrix. I am not able to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: The dimension of user_asset_matrix are 9276x13068. And Im using recommender lab. When I convert the bin matrix back to original I get a 2x2 Matrix

Answer (score 1):

I have just managed to get over this problem, although I am almost not sure how... Let me try helping you.

First of all, are you *sure* the format of the large matrix is actually `matrix` and not `data.frame` or `data.table`? Somehow, this was my problem...

In either case, assuming that the matrix has been obtained starting from a transaction list `trlist` with many many rows and two columns such as the following

```
    > dim(trlist)
    [1] 100000 2
    > colnames(trlist)
    [1] "customer" "item"
```

we can obtain a hopefully good customer-item matrix using `acast` from `reshape2` (and please forgive my OCD indentation choices):

```
    product_item <- 
        acast(
            data          = trlist, 
            formula       = customer ~ item,  
            value.var     = item,
            fun.aggregate = length
        )
```

*Now* we should be ready for:

```
    product_item    <- as(product_item, "realRatingMatrix")
    sp_product_item <- binarize(product_item, minRating = 1)
```

*If* the matrix you have doesn't come from a transaction list, you can use `melt` from the already loaded `reshape2` to obtain one, and then follow the previous steps.

I cannot guarantee that this will help you too, but it worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my code and was getting the same output even though my initial data-set had many many ratings. I was reading in a csv file, it turns out you can't simply coerce a data.frame straight to a binaryRatingMatrix without converting it to a data matrix first:

```
library(recommenderlab)
csv<-read.csv("csv.csv",header=TRUE,row.names=1)
csv<-as.matrix(csv)
csv<-as(csv,"binaryRatingMatrix)
csv
139x867 rating matrix of class 'binaryRatingMatrix' with 3944 ratings.
```

When you print csv after converting it to "binaryRatingMatrix", it should now show the correct dimensions of the variable along with the number of ratings you are expecting.